# arguments on checkbox on NativeScript Vue

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

```
<Checkbox v-model="chkbox" @tap="onTap($event)"></Checkbox>
```

I got this on my HTML, while my method looks like this:

```
onTap(args){
  console.log(args)
}
```

But I got error that goes like this

```
System.err: Calling js method onSingleTapUp failed
System.err: Error: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "I" field "AXIS_RELATIVE_X" 
in class "Landroid/view/MotionEvent;" or its superclasses
```

Can someone help me to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Where do you define $event ?

Answer (score 0):

First, change the code:

```
@tap="onTap($event)"
```

to

```
@tap="onTap"
```

Secondly, if you try logging the event, you'll get an explosion :)
So, go on with your code, do whatever you want, but don't log the event.